# What is the refresh rate of the accelerometer in the wiimote?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wii, wiimote

Does anyone know what the refresh rate of the accelerometer in the wiimote is? Is there a way to find out using Visual C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every 5.02 ms (~200Hz) according to [this page](http://angolablog.matthewwarne.com/2007/12/wiimote-experiments.html) (which has loads of great info on it, mostly in links to other articles).

> Data from with tk.wii object is 8-bit data reported every 5.02 milliseconds on average (with a 4.90 median and 5.86 in one test). The data is represented as a 0.0-1.0 value the tilt of the controller occupying 21% of that range – tilt values for the X-and Y-axis range from 0.396 to 0.608 with sharp accelerations using the entire range.

It may depend not only upon the device's capabilities, but your connection to it.

Comment: if my connection is the determining factor, how can I determine the refresh rate considering my connection in c#?

Comment: The don't make milliseconds the way they used to. Back in my days, you could get 200 Hz for a 5 ms interval.

Comment: Haha!  Er, maybe lunar milliseconds...  thanks, will update the answer.

Comment: @Omar, can you count the number of updates you get per second?  You can use `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` for decent precision timing.

Answer (score 1):

100 Hz, according to this [pdf](http://uxweek.com/slides/wiimote-projects-uxweek.pdf).